# css background gradient does not fill the whole background

Tags: css, background, gradient

I have tried a few of the fixes mentioned previously in other questions, but can't get it to work. I used the css background gradient generator at ultimate CSS but the gradient only goes half way down the page. The page is www.ncentertain.com and the css file is ncentertain.con/style14.css

Any thoughts on what I have done wrong? One solution said to put the gradient in the "html" rather than "body" css, but that didn;t seem to work.

Thanks!

Comment: [Including link to archived version of page with broken code for possible future reference](http://www.webcitation.org/6MDDApZNd)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `<html>` tag is not going down the full height of the page. Just add `height:100%;` to the styles of the html tag and it should work correctly.

PS: you should probably change the styles to the `body` instead of the `html` tag. It's better to add styling to the body, since that's what you're working with. The `height:100%;` style does need to be in the `html` tag's styles though.

Comment: that worked perfectly, thank you so much it was driving me crazy!